# How to engineer and test seasonality features?

Tags: feature-selection, feature-engineering, importance

My task is **multiclass classification** of item to buy (next).
I have a purchase history dataset with a datetime feature.
From it I could engineer many new seasonality features:

- Time of year (season, month, custom)
- Time of month (start/mid/end, custom)
- Time of week (each day, is weekend, custom)
- Time of day (day part, hour, minute, custom)
- is holiday/somehow special day, is Christmas etc.

Custom means that features do not necessarily have to be of same temporal size. As long as that feature is 'good'.

My question is: How to correctly that 'goodness' of 1/multiple features? Ideas so far:

1. Taking a set of features and measuring accuracy metrics
2. Taking a set of features and getting *feature importance*

Are those methods valid, are there more/better methods?

Also, how would I **efficiently** come up with an **ideal combination** (I assume the best encoding of real world circumstances would be a combination, not just 1) of seasonality features? Meaning, do I have to train my classifier every time for every combination I come up with, or can I dump them all in 1 training job, trusting that some combination (e.g. [*is_summer*, *is_weekend*, *is_morning*]) will crystallize itself with e.g. individual *feature importances* being higher?

Or are there some more correct/standardized processes for this kind of 'iterative feature testing'?

Also, does this depend of a type of model being used (LightGBM)?

Any answer, information or link is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!